# jquery add function call back in html attr to call in other event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, callback

i have link like this

```
<a href="#" class="open_popup" data-callback="after_close_popup_do">Open popup</a>
```

and i have this code in jquery

```
function after_close_popup_do(obj , list){
   console.log( "obj =>"+obj+"  && List =>"+list );
}

$("a.open_popup").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("shown");
   $("#popup").attr("data-callback" , $(this).attr("data-callback")) ;
   return false;
});
```

when finish what he do in the popup and click finish button

```
$("#popup a.finish_popup").click(function(){
     var callback = $("#popup").attr("data-callback");
     var o = $("#target_div") ;
     var list = {"items"=>{"a":"55","b":33}} ;
     // I shoud here use the callback function
        if( typeof window[callback] !== "function" ) {
              console.log( "your function not working" ) ;
        }else{
              window[c]( list , o ) ; // We Called your function
              console.log( "your function work fine" ) ;
        }

}) ;
```

How can i use my custom function to call as callback in this code ??

Thank you

Comment: result always `your function not working`

Comment: `window[c]` should be `window[callback]`.

Comment: soryy hand error but it dont go to this code because window[callback] not function and it return your function not working

Comment: That's just horrible, why would you pass the name of the callback as a data attribute? Also, is that fat arrow in `list` a typo, or are you trying to use ES6 ?

Comment: Is the function defined in the global scope? Only global variables get put into `window`. If it's defined inside another function, you can't access it that way.

Comment: i want to pass the function because i want to use other function in other events like
`<a href="#" class="open_popup2" data-callback="do_this_function_not_the_other">Open popup</a>`

Comment: @Barmar you mean i should call my function as 
`window[after_close_popup_do] = function (obj , list){
   console.log( "obj =>"+obj+"  && List =>"+list );
}`

Comment: Thank you @adeneo and Barmar  it worked with  Barmar Solution
-------------------------
adeneo : why you sayed : That's just horrible ??

Comment: I said that because it is. Just use two different classes, with two different event handlers etc. there's no need to pass a name of a callback as a string from data attributes. There's a reason noone does this, and you haven't seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to look up function names that way. Instead, use your own object to keep track of the functions:

```
var callbacks = {
    after_close_popup_do: function(obj , list){
       console.log( "obj =>"+obj+"  && List =>"+list );
    },
    ...
};
```

Then look it up in this object rather than `window`:

```
$("#popup a.finish_popup").click(function(){
    var callback = $("#popup").attr("data-callback");
    var o = $("#target_div") ;
    var list = {"items"=>{"a":"55","b":33}} ;
    // I shoud here use the callback function
    if( typeof callbacks[callback] !== "function" ) {
        console.log( "your function not working" ) ;
    } else {
        callbacks[callback]( list , o ) ; // We Called your function
        console.log( "your function work fine" ) ;
    }
});
```

This will allow you to use local functions; your original code requires the functions to be defined in the global context so they'll be added to `window`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar my custom object is good idea for me and it worked